# Always returning null in NSString return function

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code where I want to convert decimal odds to fractional odds. However the function `findNearestWholeInteger` always returns `null`.

```
- (NSString *)displayOddWithFormat:(NSString *)decimalOdd {

   if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FractionalOdds"] == YES) {
       float oddsF = decimalOdd.floatValue;
       oddsF = oddsF - 1.0f;
       return [self findNearestWholeInteger:oddsF andInitial:oddsF andBottom:1];
   } else {
       return odd;
   }
}

- (NSString *)findNearestWholeInteger:(float)odds andInitial:(float)initial andBottom:(float)bottom {

   NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:odds];
   NSString *floatString = [numberValue stringValue];
   NSArray *floatStringComps = [floatString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

   if (floatStringComps.count == 1) {
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f/%.f", odds, bottom];
   } else {
       bottom += 1;
       odds += initial;
       [self findNearestWholeInteger:odds andInitial:initial andBottom:bottom];
       return nil;
   }
}
```

Any ideas where I need to adapt my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want a method to return `nil`, don't use the statement `return nil;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want:

```
return [self findNearestWholeInteger:odds andInitial:initial andBottom:bottom];
//return nil;
```

(not that I really understand what the method is doing).